# How map $p(x) = x^n$ acts on conjugacy classes

Tags: abstract-algebra

If I had a group G and a map $p(x) = x^n$ would it act differently on my conjugacy classes? My friend told me that it would, but I don't see how it would change anything with regard to our conjugacy classes. Does it have to do with $x^n$ = $x*x*...*x$ where $x$ is multiplied $n$ times?

**EDIT:**

I think this has to deal with cases of $n$ being even or odd

**EDIT 2:**

My thinking:

If the order of the element in the conjugacy class is odd and $n$ is odd then it leaves the conjugacy class fixed if $n$ is even and the order of the element in the conjugacy class is even it leaves that conjugacy class fixed

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "act differently on my conjugacy classes"?

Comment: Would it change the order of the conjugacy classes or affect them some way. I'm just trying to see how p would act on the conjugacy classes

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ are conjugate, $p(x)$ and $p(y)$ are conjugate (but the converse is not true). The conjugacy class of $x$ and the conjugacy class of $p(x)$ need not have the same order. Is any of this what you're looking for?

Comment: Also note that in general, $p$ is not a homomorphism.

Comment: So if $p$ acted on our conjugacy classes then our $p(x)$ could have a different conjugacy class? I was just told that $p$ would act on these conjugacy classes and was asked how it acts on these conjugacy classes

Comment: Yes, $x$ and $p(x)$ may belong to two different conjugacy classes.

Comment: if n is even would it leave the conjugacy classes the same but if n was odd would it change them?

Comment: It can change the conjugacy classes whether $n$ is even or odd. To build up your understanding, I suggest you try out some examples for various groups $G$ and various exponents $n$ that you know well. Knowing examples can be better than thinking in the dark.

Comment: I looked at examples in $S_2$ and $S_3$ but I do not see how this even affects the conjugacy classes